# Show exact numbers in excels formula calculation

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have numbers in cells like 001 , 011, 01, 03, 013 ( I used the custom cell formating 00 and/or 000) and when I use a formula on them to show in one cell all together I get it like this : 1 0 31 2 0 7 4 instead of 01 00 31 02 00 007.004. What should I do.

Screenshot:

https://s4.postimg.org/61q9ybj31/image.jpg

Comment: You should share the formula you are using so we could assist.

Comment: Simple adding formula "=AE2&" "&AF2&" "&AG2&" "&AH2&" "&AI2&" "&AJ2&"."&AK2"

Comment: if the leading zeroes are done through Formatting this will not produce the results as it will drop formatting and just keep the values. Please see my answer below that converts the values to text in the format described and then concatenates them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming values on A1 to D1, formula would be:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00#")&" "&TEXT(B1,"00#")&" "&TEXT(C1,"00#")&" "&TEXT(D1,"00#")
```

The format must be specified in the formula for each one which should work for your use as seems that each number has different expected formatting. It will then format the value as text with the specific formatting and then concatenate them with spaces or whatever delimiter you use in between.

EDIT: per OP clarifications in comment solution could be assuming a 2,1,3,2 length of digits for 4 columns of numbers (which you can change inside the `REPT()`) formula would be:

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT("0",2-LEN(A1))&REPT("#",LEN(A1)))&" "&TEXT(B1,REPT("0",1-LEN(B1))&REPT("#",LEN(B1)))&" "&TEXT(C1,REPT("0",3-LEN(C1))&REPT("#",LEN(C1)))&" "&TEXT(D1,REPT("0",2-LEN(D1))&REPT("#",LEN(D1)))
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solves 90% of my problems, the problem is some cells have 1 number, and some have 11 numbers, so when I setup the code to have 0# or 00# changes the output. Please check the marked cell on screenshot. Can this be avoided somehow ?

Comment: Can you confirm that the format of each column remains consistent? I have figured a way to vary the formatting inside the `TEXT()` depending on the number of digits of the numbers. But you must know the total number of characters that each column should have as it must be hardcoded into the formula. Edit of formula will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that will return the result exactly as it shows in the original columns, including with the formatting.  No need to know the formatting beforehand.

```
Option Explicit
Function ConcatWithFormat(rg As Range) As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long

ReDim V(1 To rg.Count - 1)
For I = 1 To rg.Count - 1
    V(I) = rg(I).Text
Next I

V(I - 1) = V(I - 1) & "." & rg(I).Text

ConcatWithFormat = Join(V)

End Function
```

[image]